# Different querysets in one view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make the standard blog post web application using Django. I have multiple models in one applications. I want to display at a few posts from all the models to create an index, for which I will need to have multiple queryset inside my view for each model,  which I don't know how to do.

blog/models.py

```
class topicone(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class topictwo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class topicthree(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.indeview.as_view(), name="indexview"),

    path('<int:pk>', DetailView.as_view(
        model = topicone,
        template_name = "blogs/topicone.html"
    )),
]
```

blog/views.py

```
class indeview(ListView):
    model = topicone
    template_name = "blog/index.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return topicone.objects.all()
```

views.py is quite useless as I am only using one model here. I tried writing a standalone view that didn't inherit from any other generic view so I could just create different contexts and pass multiple dictionaries in a view but that didn't seem to work. Here's how I tried to work that out

```
blogone = topicone.objects.all()
blogdict = {
    'id': blogone
}

blogtwo = topictwo.objects.all()
blog2dict = {'id': blogtwo}

return render (request, 'blog/index.html', blogdict, blogtwo)
```

this view only displayed data from only one model, `blogtwo`

Comment: Why do you have three identical models in the first place?

Comment: I was trying to create categories, so one blog will be about traveling, one about programming, one about something else I guess. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Then you should use one model with a `category` field.

Comment: Could you help me understand how I would incorporate categories field in this current for loop that I am using to display the data `{% for topicone in object_list %}
            <h1>{{ topicone.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href="/blog/{{topic.id}}">{{ topic.title }}</a></h1>
        {% endfor %}` @DanielRoseman

Comment: as Daniel said, you should consider using one model plus one more field named `category` that will contain the different category `traveling`, `programming` and so one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider something like:

```
blogone = topicone.objects.all()
blogtwo = topictwo.objects.all()

return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'blogone': blogone, 'blogtwo': blogtwo})
```

As the render params are `request`, `template`, and `context`.

*Reference: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/_)*